# Why doesn't a photon lose energy according to $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, mass-energy

As photons are massless thus by $E=mc^2$,
the energy should be zero right? or should it be?
I would be pleased to be corrected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $E = mc^2$ apply to photons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6202/)

Comment: Yes Thanks, it does answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full formula is $E= \sqrt{c^2p^2+m^2 c^4}$, so for massless particles $E= pc$. The momentum $p$ of of photon is given by $p= h/\lambda$, so, from $\lambda \nu=c$ where $\nu$ is the frequency, we have  $E= h\nu$ .

Comment: From E=hν, plank's constant is fixed, so does every wavelength of light has a fixed specific energy?

Comment: Yes. Every photon has energy proportional to its frequency.  $N$ photons of the same frequency  have a total energy of  $E=Nh\nu$.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike! very cool